# Name of formula: $\mathrm{max}\{n \in \mathbb{N} : (x^n \mid y)\} = \mathrm{min}\{\nu_p(y) /\!/ \nu_p(x) : p \mbox{ prime factor of } x\}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, terminology

I'm pretty sure the following is true:

> **Proposition.** Let $x$ and $y$ denote natural numbers. Then: $$\mathrm{max}\{n \in \mathbb{N} : (x^n \mid y)\} = \mathrm{min}\{\nu_p(y) /\!/ \nu_p(x) : p \mbox{ is a prime factor of } x\},$$
>
> where $/\!/$ denotes floored division.

We can use this to find the number of trailing zeroes in the decimal expansion of the factorial of a number.

I'll also remark that both either side of the above formula can reasonably be taken as the definition of $\nu_x(y)$.

> **Question.** Does the above formula have a name?

Here's an example of how to use it. Lets predict the number of trailing zeroes in the decimal expansion of $(25!),$ or in other words we're trying to find $\nu_{10}(25!)$. A calculator tells us the answer is $6$:

$$25! = 15511210043330985984000000$$

But why $6$, and how could we have found this without a calculator? Well, let $x=10$ and $y=25!$ in our formula. Then:

$\mathrm{max}\{n \in \mathbb{N} : (10^n \mid 25!)\}$

$ = \mathrm{min}\{\nu_p(25!) /\!/ \nu_p(10) : p \mbox{ is a prime factor of } 10\}$

$ = \mathrm{min}\{\nu_2(25!) /\!/ \nu_2(10), \nu_5(25!) /\!/ \nu_5(10)\}$

$ = \mathrm{min}\{\nu_2(25!), \nu_5(25!)\}$

$ = \nu_5(25!)$

$ = \nu_5(5) + \nu_5(10) + \nu_5(15) + \nu_5(20) + \nu_5(25)$

$ = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2$

$ = 6$

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the statement in your question doesn't go by any particular name. This may be due to the fact that $\nu_p(n)$ (prime $p$) is used much more commonly in mathematics than $\nu_m(n)$ (where $m \in \mathbb{N}$). If you're looking for a proof of the statement, I might be able to provide one.

Answer (score 1):

This is well know as the **Legendre Formula** saying :

$$v_p(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\lfloor n/p^k\rfloor=\lfloor n/p\rfloor+\lfloor n/p^2\rfloor+...
$$.

Combined with for a composed number $x=pq$ with $p$ and $q 
$ prime.

$$ v_x(n)=\min(v_p(n), v_q(n)) $$

I hope it answer to your question.

Comment: I'll give you the bounty because what you've written looks relevant, but honestly I'm not quite sure of the connection. Are you basically saying that there's another way of working out $\nu_{10}(25!)$ that's different to my approach?

Comment: Yes is it actually another way using the formula above. Although they must be equivalent.